# read.table skip lines with different numbers of elements

Tags: r

I am trying to combine about 20 data files (txt format, 10 columns), some of which have secondary headers (leading to the wrong number of elements in the column) in the middle of the data (1400 rows in).

The code I am using to combine the files"

```
data_path <- "/Users/datalocation/"
filenames <- list.files(data_path, full.names = F, pattern = "*myfile*", recursive = TRUE) 
selectfl1a <- function(x) {out <- read.table(x, col.names = ColNames,
                                             colClasses = c(rep("numeric", 4),
                                                            rep("NULL", 6)))}
test <- lapply(filenames, selectfl1a) %>% cbind()  #this step throws the error

testdf <- as.data.frame(t(test))
colnames(testdf) <- filenames
rowtest <- lapply(filenames, selectfl1a) %>% bind_rows(.id="id")
```

When the code works, it gives me a 4 column data set with each file denoted by id. Because of the rows that have the wrong number of elements, I get "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :
scan() expected 'a real', got 'CURVE2'"

One of the columns my code throws out contains a string of periods, and the columns I keep contain numbers in scientific format, so when I tried to use `grep("[[:alpha]]")`, it threw out everything.

Is there any way to throw out the rows with different numbers of elements while maintaining the structure of my import?

EDIT: fill=TRUE does not work, because of the colClasses section, which coerces the first 4 columns to be numeric: without that, the cbind command does not work. I can use `colClasses = c(re("character", 4), rep(NULL",6))`, but I am not sure how to convert the resulting table back to numeric values.

Here are a few lines of the file: copying them into a text file and attempting to import recreates the error.
1398    699.5   3.98152E-001    1.43132E-005    0.00000E+000    3.98006E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00
1399    700 3.99150E-001    1.43272E-005    0.00000E+000    3.99006E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00
1400    700.5   4.00156E-001    1.43400E-005    0.00000E+000    4.00006E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00
CURVE2  TABLE
Pt  T   Vf  Im  Vu  Sig Ach IERange Over    Temp
#   s   V vs. Ref.  A   V   V   V   #   bits    deg C
1401    701 3.99153E-001    1.42592E-005    0.00000E+000    3.99006E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00
1402    701.5   3.98159E-001    1.41958E-005    0.00000E+000    3.98006E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00
1403    702 3.97134E-001    1.41371E-005    0.00000E+000    3.97007E-001    0.00000E+000    8   ...........  0.00

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide example files, paste couple of lines that would include rows with issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `fill=TRUE` argument to read.table which pads out lines with a deficient number of fields. These rows of the data frame can be filtered out later.

I suggest workflow could be:

1. Read all columns as text.
2. Remove rows starting with "CURVE".
3. Remove columns filled with NAs.
4. Convert required columns back to numeric.
5. Use bind_rows for multiple data frames.

Comment: The work flow is good as long as you know what the problem rows contain.  It would be nice to have something that would work even if the problem rows started with different words, but I think this is the best option.